# Simple way to rotate dplyr's tibble summary

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am looking for a simple way to rotate [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr)'s `tibble` summary.

Say I am doing something like this,

```
# install.packages(c("dplyr"), dependencies = TRUE)
library(dplyr) 

mtcars %>% 
    group_by(am)  %>%
    summarise(
        n = n(),
        Mean_disp = mean(disp),
        Mean_hp = mean(hp),
        Mean_qsec = mean(qsec),
        Mean_drat = mean(drat)
             )
#>     # A tibble: 2 x 6
#>      am     n Mean_disp  Mean_hp Mean_qsec Mean_drat
#>   <dbl> <int>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1     0    19  290.3789 160.2632  18.18316  3.286316
#> 2     1    13  143.5308 126.8462  17.36000  4.050000
```

But, what I would like is to get an output more or less like this,

```
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>    am <dbl>             0           1
#>   n <int>              19          13
#>   Mean_disp <dbl>     290.3789    143.5308
#>   Mean_hp <dbl>       160.2631    126.8462
#>   Mean_qsec <dbl>      18.183158   17.36000
#>   Mean_drat <dbl>       3.286316    4.050000
```

I realize I can use `t()`, but that transform the tibble to a list and mess up the formatting.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48282782/simply-way-to-rotate-dplyrs-tibble-summary. Try wrapping the t function call with as.data.frame()

Comment: @icj I think your link is wrong.

Comment: @icj a question that's a duplicate of itself?

Comment: @useR, yes, my apologies. I'll dig up the appropriate link asap.

Comment: Try skimr package

Answer (score 6):

Maybe *gather* then *spread* again:

```
library(dplyr) 
library(tidyr)

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(am)  %>%
  summarise(
    n = n(),
    Mean_disp = mean(disp),
    Mean_hp = mean(hp),
    Mean_qsec = mean(qsec),
    Mean_drat = mean(drat)) %>%
  gather(key = key, value = value, -am) %>% 
  spread(key = am, value = value)


# # A tibble: 5 x 3
#         key        `0`      `1`
# *     <chr>      <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1 Mean_disp 290.378947 143.5308
# 2 Mean_drat   3.286316   4.0500
# 3   Mean_hp 160.263158 126.8462
# 4 Mean_qsec  18.183158  17.3600
# 5         n  19.000000  13.0000
```

---

Another option, *gather* before *group_by*, then get mean for all selected columns, then *spread* again (but not sure how to add `n()`):

```
mtcars %>% 
  select(am, disp, hp, qsec, drat) %>% 
  gather(key = key, value = value, -am) %>% 
  group_by(am, key)  %>%
  summarise(myMean = mean(value)) %>%
  spread(key = am, value = myMean)

# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#     key        `0`      `1`
# * <chr>      <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1  disp 290.378947 143.5308
# 2  drat   3.286316   4.0500
# 3    hp 160.263158 126.8462
# 4  qsec  18.183158  17.3600
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It does the job, it is however kinda _unsimply_. I say that in relation to my title _simply way to_ ... as you also point out ` _gather_ then _spread_ again.' I'll hold back on recognizing your answer to see if anyone comes up with something simple.

Comment: @EricFail added another option, again not sure if it is any simpler.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks! It feels to me like there's something to this whole `tidyverse` logic I am still not seeing. Regardless, I appreciate your answer very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
  new_tibble <- as.data.frame(t(mt_cars_df)) %>% 
  as_tibble()

  new_tibble$name <- names(mt_cars_df) %>%
    select(name, V1, V2)
```

according to [this](https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble/issues/123), row.names are deprecated in tibbles, so adding them as a key column would the logical way of handling the situation. This leaves a tibble that requires reordering the columns.

Comment: Isn't this simply wrapping `t()` in a `as.data.frame()`? Did you note my final comment in my question? If I wanted to wrap a transpose in anything it would be a `as_tibble()`.